# API Job Search v2 - documentation Linkedin

Tags: linkedin-api

We need to develop internally a service that allows you to read and collect Job Posts of other companies, applying filters (company name, specific keywords).
We found the endpoint of the API https://api.linkedin.com/v1/job-search we would like to know if there is also the v2, online we have not retrieved any information.
The information we need to collect with the API is:
- title job post
- Location of the workplace (Country and Region)
- Company location (country, city)
- Date of publication of the advertisement

Thank you Paolo

Answer (score 2):

I've been investigating integration with this api as well with no luck. I will just share what I have found so far.

1. There's no version 2 of this API documented anywhere in the public space (so best assume it does not exist) - there's documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/ & https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v1
2. You need implement oauth2-client-credentials-flow as documented here - https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v2/oauth2-client-credentials-flow
3. To activate oauth2-client-credentials-flow you need to signup to 1 of the enterprise products **NOT** Marketing Developer Platform - but its not clear which of their available products actually contains the job-search-api.

I have logged a ticket with their support team for clarity on way forward & will be sure to update this post once I get something meaningful; so far, its just feels like i'm going around in circles

Comment: Thanks Munyah. We have also opened a ticket with linkedin

Comment: We also tried to talk to the business contact. They'll let us know something.
Munyah did you try to call the end-point by writing?

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/job-search

Comment: aww, @PaoloQuagliarella I can see that the v2 endpoint here is indeed responding & requires oauth2 authentication; which by deduction is the same issue i'm facing with the v1 endpoint as well. My ticket with their dev team is still waiting for a response :(

Comment: This is the  response from the LinkedIn Dev Support team - _"All Marketing Developer Platform permissions are three-legged permissions. Two-legged auth is not available for any marketing use cases.

All calls must be made on behalf of an individual LinkedIn member based on only those ads accounts or company pages to which that member has the correct permissions.

Thanks"_  --- I do not know what to make of this response from LinkedIn, it is neither clear nor does it answer the original question. So now, I will respond to them and wait another month before I get another cryptic message?

Comment: @munyah did they ever get back to you?

Comment: @GCQ nope, that was end of the line from them & my consequently my desire to integrate with their service.

Answer (score 2):

If you refer to the LinkedIn Recommended Jobs API documentation (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/jobs/recommended-jobs ), we can see that LinkedIn Talent Solutions" is written from which I assumed that the API is a product of the LinkedIn partners program under the category -LinkedIn talent solutions (https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply).

However, the documentation for the Talent solutions category has no mention of recommended jobs API. Hence, it is quite hard to tell where we can acquire permission for the API. I have not been able to find any other API which will be useful for the task. 
Recommended Jobs API returns jobs posted on LinkedIn which match the user's profile. The output will return job id, title, company name, location description and job description. There is no option of keyword search from my understanding.

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, A_Kriti, this is part of the issue. The talent solutions that you describe above is as you say, recommended jobs based on a user - which is not what we are after at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

This is not yet supported by v2. Although it supposed to be the first thing they should support, it is long due. I may suggest you look at how LinkedIn does the job search on their website. They use a service called Voyager and that pretty much has all the endpoints you'll ever need to get work done.

Have a look: https://linkedin.api-docs.io/v1.0/search/yKaMAGcbmsJBswTCb

Go to the LinkedIn website, do a job search. F12 is your friend ;)